El Slider del hero no se ve bien en iOS
Tengo una página creada en wordpress con Oxygen, hice cambio de unas fotos del slider y ahora resulta que se ve bien en desktop pero en responsive solo se ve bien en Android, en iOS se ve fatal!! Alguna sugerencia para crear un CSS para iOS

Hola Maria, puedes darnos un poco mas de información para poder ayudarte?, revisa el recorrido de bienvenida para saber como hacer preguntas correctamente un salud

Podrias brindar mas detalle del sitio, como se ve en iOS, que navegador de iOS estas usando, link de la página, etc.
No obstante, si estas utilizando Chrome en ios y te sugiero que en los estilos uses svh y svw en caso de que estes usando vh o vw.
